# Laravel session/storage is empty on refresh

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code:

```
            echo 'First try: <br />';
            $input = Session::get('input');
            pre($input, false);

            echo 'Second try: <br />';
            Session::put('input', 'test');
            pre(Session::get('input'));
```

which gives the following output the first time it's loaded :

```
First try:
Second try:
test
```

That is expected on the first time, however when i reload the page, i get the exact same output. All data is just lost after a refresh.

I know it's not flash data, but i can't find out why it's not storing the data. I'm using file based sessions and Xampp on windows (The same happens when using artisan serve).

The storage folder is writable.

Edit: Just tried with database sessions, same result. And i'm doing this directly in the routes file, so theres no other code that can mess it up.

The pre function:

```
function pre( $data , $kill = true)
{
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($data,true).'</pre>';
    if($kill){
      exit;
}
```

Comment: What does the `pre` function do? If it does a `die`/`exit` it may short-circuit the Laravel session storage functionality.

Comment: Alright ill try to do it in a controller without killing the script, ill post the results. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Please post your comment as answer so i can accept it! Thank you!

Comment: @ceejayoz That's very interesting behaviour and very misleading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel's session data is written as part of the response shutdown process. This is for efficiency reasons - if you're making dozens of `Session::put` calls in a request, it's better to make them all at once in bulk.

As a result, if you don't cause a response with something like `View::make` or `Response::json` or what have you and instead `exit` or `die`, session data won't be written as you've short circuited the response lifecycle.

Comment: Very useful! I was testing some things and die-and-dumped the output but was wondering why my session kept resetting. Thanks!